# Spring Boot Hystrix maximumSize not working

Tags: spring-boot, threadpool, hystrix

I was using Spring Boot and Hystrix in my Project

Here is my pom dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <cxf.version>3.3.1</cxf.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my application.properties

```
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize=2
hystrix.threadpool.default.maximumSize=200
hystrix.threadpool.default.maxQueueSize=50
hystrix.threadpool.default.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=50
hystrix.threadpool.default.keepAliveTimeMinutes=1
hystrix.threadpool.default.allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize=true
```

With this config, my app cannot hanlde 100ccu. It's shown this error: `"java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Rejected command because thread-pool queueSize is at rejection threshold"`.

I can see the logging only create 2 hystrix thread to handle request

```
hystrix-MyService-1
hystrix-MyService-2
```

Why it cannot create more thread to handle request while I was config maximumSize=200?

If I increase the coreSize=200 for example, I can see they never terminate.
So How can I set a small coreSize but still can handle more requests if needed (up to maximumSize conccurent thread) and then release them when no new requests ?

Answer (score 0):

`hystrix.threadpool.default.maximumSize` configuration works only if `hystrix.threadpool.default.maxQueueSize=-1`

If having queue is necessary in your case - then there is no way to create and then release extra threads in the pool.

Article with detailed explanations: https://programmer.help/blogs/hystrix-thread-pool-configuration.html